# Permission problems with uWSGI and Modoboa

Tags: permissions, email-server, dovecot, file-permissions, uwsgi

I have run a manual installation of Modoboa (https://modoboa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#manual-installation), which runs a webapp in uWSGI. I moved the static content to /var/www/html and let the rest sit in /opt/modoboa, which is owned by a modoboa user. There are some cron jobs which should be run as modoboa user, too.

If I start the uWSGI server as user modoboa by setting `uid` and `guid = modoboa` in the uWSGI ini file, I can access the webapp and use all functionality. But the scripts which should be executed by the modoboa user prompt me for a password - and I can't figure out which part of the system requires root access.

Following commands were run as root in order to perform the installation:

```
mkdir -p /opt/modoboa
cd /opt/modoboa
virtualenv --python python3 ./env
source ./env/bin/activate
pip install mysqlclient
pip install modoboa

modoboa-admin.py deploy instance --collectstatic --domain mail.mydomain.com --dburl default:mysql://modoboa:$db_user_password-modoboa@[localhost]/modoboa

chown -R modoboa:modoboa env/
chown -R modoboa:modoboa instance/
mkdir -p /var/www/html/mail
mv instance/frontend/ instance/media/ instance/sitestatic/ /var/www/html/mail/

pip install uwsgi
echo "[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:3031
chdir = /opt/modoboa/instance
module = instance.wsgi:application
uid = modoboa
gid = modoboa
master = true
harakiri = 60
processes = 4
vhost = true
no-default-app = true
log-master = true
single-interpreter = true
logto = /opt/modoboa/modoboa.log
die-on-term = true" > /opt/modoboa/modoboa.ini
touch /opt/modoboa/modoboa.log
chown -R modoboa:modoboa /opt/modoboa/modoboa.log /opt/modoboa/modoboa.ini

echo '[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve modoboa
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/modoboa/env/bin/uwsgi --ini /opt/modoboa/modoboa.ini
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target' > /etc/systemd/system/modoboa.service
systemctl enable modoboa.service
systemctl start modoboa.service
```

Edit:

After some further investigation, I could find out the source of the problem. I added the modoboa user to the dovecot group, but that didn't help

```
    available_schemes = get_dovecot_schemes()
  File "/opt/modoboa/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modoboa/core/password_hashers/__init__.py", line 49, in get_dovecot_schemes
    retcode, schemes = doveadm_cmd("pw -l")
  File "/opt/modoboa/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modoboa/lib/sysutils.py", line 76, in doveadm_cmd
    return exec_cmd("{} {}".format(dpath, params),
  File "/opt/modoboa/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modoboa/lib/sysutils.py", line 39, in exec_cmd
    output = process.communicate(*c_args)[0]
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1121, in communicate
    stdout = self.stdout.read()
KeyboardInterrupt
```